# How to install Python 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: python3, idle-python

I want to install Python 3.5.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have been searching but I still can't figure it out. I tried to find Python 3.5.1 in the Software Center but I couldn't find it.

Edit: I actually want to run IDLE 3, the Python IDE for Python 3.

Can someone tell me a step by step instruction on how to install it?

Comment: 16.04 comes with Python 3.5.1. Can you try `which python3` and `python3 --version` and give us the outputs?

Comment: If 16.04 comes with Python 3.5.1, how come I can't find the IDLE when searching for it?

Comment: Can you first tell us what `which python3` say? I want to make sure Python 3 is already on your system. As for your question regarding IDLE, IDLE is not installed by default. There is no reason why Python 3 _must_ come together with IDLE. If you want it, do `sudo apt install idle3`.

Comment: which python3 returns /usr/local/bin/python3, python3 --version returns Python 3.5.1

Comment: I tried sudo apt install idle3 and there is an error saying E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg return an error code (1)

Comment: I can't resolve the error but I did download IDLE3. How should I fix the error?

Comment: Search this site for that error; there are plenty of questions and answers regarding that. If you can't find a solution, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: No problem at all. Enjoy using Ubuntu and Python!

Answer (score 12):

Python 3.5.1 is installed on Ubuntu 16.04 by default. You can verify that by running the command `python3 --version` in a terminal.

Now, IDLE for Python 3 is in the package `idle3` and part of the default Python distribution but it's not installed on Ubuntu by default. You can do so with Software Center or your favourite package manager. On the command-line you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

If that gives you an error as you say in the comments, please edit your question with the "edit" link below it to include the error messages verbatim (and send me a message in the comments to notify me of the change), or ask a [new question](/questions/ask) with the same information.